# Existe Master Page em PHP?

Tags: php

É uma pergunta recorrente que tenho em relação ao PHP, sou novo em programação em PHP e estou desenvolvendo um projeto disso, fiz da seguinte forma, funciona porém gostaria de uma forma mais prática em relação a isso. Criei um **file *header.php*** com apenas o **Header** da página e um ***footer.php*** com apenas o **Footer**. Abaixo o código:

```
<?php require('header.php') ?>

*//content here*

<?php require('footer.php') ?>
```

existe algum framework, plugin ou algo do tipo para facilitar a utilização de Master Page no PHP?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um template engine para fazer isso, o Smarty é um dos mais populares. Com ele, você cria páginas modelo com a extensão .tpl, e dentro destas páginas, você coloca o HTML e códigos de marcação,que serão substituídos pela sua página PHP. Por exemplo simples, você poderia ter um template com este conteúdo:

```html
Mensagem: {$msg}
```

Para personalizar a mensagem, você faria isso na sua página PHP:

```html
<!--?php
include "smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php";
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty--->template_dir = "smarty/templates";
$smarty->compile_dir = "smarty/templates_c";
$smarty->config_dir = "smarty/configs";
$smarty->assign("msg", "Hello World!");
$smarty->display("meu_arquivo_de_template.tpl");
?>
```

Aqui tem a documentação:

https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/